# Is jQuery interpreting it wrong? or Drupal outputting wrong?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm facing a peculiar problem. My Drupal website uses Jquery 1.4.4 version.

As you all know, Drupal outputs `Drupal.settings` json to Javascript as:

**when I enable `devel_themer` module**:

The following is the output

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {
   "basePath":"\/d7\/",
   "pathPrefix":"",
   "ajaxPageState":{
      "theme":"bartik",
      "theme_token":"KC2-1Z9CN5PCxDyAq_W8FGBQBOOnwt8AyoeX1UDBoP8",
      "js":{
         "misc\/jquery.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.once.js":1,
         "misc\/drupal.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.widget.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.cookie.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.form.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.js":1,
         "misc\/ajax.js":1,
         "misc\/progress.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/krumo\/krumo.js":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/devel_krumo_path.js":1
      },
      "css":{
         "modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.resizable.css":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,
         "modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,
         "modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,
         "modules\/node\/node.css":1,
         "modules\/search\/search.css":1,
         "modules\/user\/user.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/krumo\/skins\/default\/skin.css":1,
         "modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/devel_themer_ie_fix.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/layout.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/style.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/colors.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/print.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie6.css":1
      }
   },
   "thmrStrings":{
      "themer_info":"Themer info",
      "toggle_throbber":" \u003Cimg src=\u0022\/d7\/sites\/all\/modules\/devel_themer\/loader-little.gif\u0022 alt=\u0022loading\u0022 class=\u0022throbber\u0022 width=\u002216\u0022 height=\u002216\u0022 style=\u0022display:none\u0022 \/\u003E",
      "parents":"Parents: ",
      "function_called":"Function called: ",
      "template_called":"Template called: ",
      "candidate_files":"Candidate template files: ",
      "preprocessors":"Preprocess functions: ",
      "processors":"Process functions: ",
      "candidate_functions":"Candidate function names: ",
      "drupal_api_docs":"link to Drupal API documentation",
      "source_link_title":"link to source code",
      "function_arguments":"Function Arguments",
      "template_variables":"Template Variables",
      "file_used":"File used: ",
      "duration":"Duration: ",
      "api_site":"http:\/\/api.drupal.org\/",
      "drupal_version":"7",
      "source_link":"\/d7\/devel\/source?file="
   },
   "thmr_popup":"  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-fixeder\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-relativer\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv id=\u0022themer-popup\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022topper\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cspan class=\u0022close\u0022\u003EX\u003C\/span\u003E Drupal Themer Information\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv id=\u0022parents\u0022 class=\u0022row\u0022\u003E\n\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022info row\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022starter\u0022\u003EClick on any element to see information about the Drupal theme function or template that created it.\u003C\/div\u003E\n        \u003Cdl\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022key-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022key\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022used\u0022\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022candidates-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022candidates\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022preprocessors-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022preprocessors\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdt class=\u0022processors-type\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dt\u003E\n          \u003Cdd class=\u0022processors\u0022\u003E\n\n          \u003C\/dd\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022duration\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n        \u003C\/dl\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/info --\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022attributes row\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022themer-variables\u0022\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/attributes --\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\u003C!-- \/themer-popup --\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \u003C\/div\u003E",
   "overlay":{
      "paths":{
         "admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*\ndevel\/*\nnode\/*\/devel\nnode\/*\/devel\/*\ncomment\/*\/devel\ncomment\/*\/devel\/*\nuser\/*\/devel\nuser\/*\/devel\/*\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\/*",
         "non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"
      },
      "pathPrefixes":[

      ],
      "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"
   },
   "tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height"
});
```

and in the browser console, as you can see in the following screenshot `Drupal.settings` object has some strange objects. 
[image]

**What is strange about this?**

When I try to output  in browser console, it says undefinied. But According to Drupal.settings json, there should be a `Drupal.settings.thmrStrings` object. Instead of showing these meaningful objects, according to json it shows generated some strange objects like `Drupal.settings.thmr_1`, `Drupal.settings.thmr_2`, `Drupal.settings.thmr_3` .. `Drupal.settings.thmr_94`. Where are these `Drupal.settings.thmr_*` objects coming from? They are not in the json? Why are the objects not according to jSON?

The error that you see in the screenshot is caused because of this. The javascript file `devel_themer.js` is accessing a sub-object of `Drupal.settings.thmrStrings` but its not getting it. Thats is the main problem why I got behind this.

**when I disable `devel_themer` module**:

The following is the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {
   "basePath":"\/d7\/",
   "pathPrefix":"",
   "ajaxPageState":{
      "theme":"bartik",
      "theme_token":"KC2-1Z9CN5PCxDyAq_W8FGBQBOOnwt8AyoeX1UDBoP8",
      "js":{
         "misc\/jquery.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.once.js":1,
         "misc\/drupal.js":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.min.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.ba-bbq.js":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.js":1,
         "modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,
         "misc\/jquery.cookie.js":1,
         "sites\/all\/modules\/devel\/devel_krumo_path.js":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.js":1
      },
      "css":{
         "modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,
         "modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.core.css":1,
         "misc\/ui\/jquery.ui.theme.css":1,
         "modules\/overlay\/overlay-parent.css":1,
         "modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1,
         "modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,
         "modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,
         "modules\/node\/node.css":1,
         "modules\/search\/search.css":1,
         "modules\/user\/user.css":1,
         "modules\/shortcut\/shortcut.css":1,
         "modules\/toolbar\/toolbar.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/layout.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/style.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/colors.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/print.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie.css":1,
         "themes\/bartik\/css\/ie6.css":1
      }
   },
   "overlay":{
      "paths":{
         "admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*\ndevel\/*\nnode\/*\/devel\nnode\/*\/devel\/*\ncomment\/*\/devel\ncomment\/*\/devel\/*\nuser\/*\/devel\nuser\/*\/devel\/*\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\/*",
         "non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"
      },
      "pathPrefixes":[

      ],
      "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"
   },
   "tableHeaderOffset":"Drupal.toolbar.height"
});
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

and in the browser console as you can see the following picture `Drupal.settings` object is interpreted properly. I mean, objects are as per json. There are no strange objects like in the above case.

[image]

**Question:** What is causing this strange behaviour? How to rectify it?

Comment: What do you think is odd?

Comment: Have to agree. What's odd about this behavior? It's basically providing the thmr_ tags to the API so it can do fancy highlighting.

Comment: @MPD: I've prettified json and added `What is strange about this?` section to my question. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those objects are coming from the [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.

The module relies on data attributes on HTML elements to do it's thing.  It either attaches to the element directly, or it will inject a `<span>`.  All of the data elements are of the form `data-thmr="thmr_XXX"`.   The data value matches up with an entry in `Drupal.settings`, and contains all of the theme information for that particular element, and is used to build the fancy box that appears when you click on something.

When I do a view-source on a site where I have Theme Developer enabled, I see the data attributes in the code, and I see the data elements in the DOM, and I see the objects in `Drupal.settings`.  I also see the `Drupal.settings.thmrStrings` object.

However, if you poke through the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/devel_themer) and search for "thmrStrings", you will run across this [issue](https://drupal.org/node/2199439), which talks about incompatibilities with the 2.x branch of [simplehtmldom](https://drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom).  The simplehtmldom module has this warning on it page:

> **If you're using Theme developer please note that it's currently incompatible with simplehtmldom 7.x-2.x. Use 7.x-1.12 instead. More details [#2199439: Incompatible with simplehtmldom 7.x-2.x](https://drupal.org/node/2199439)**

So, I would disable Theme Developer, then disable an uninstall simpledom API, download and enable simplehtmldom-7.x-1.12, and then enable Theme Developer again.

Answer (score 1):

They come from Drupal.settings. When devel_themer is enabled, there is a second block `jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings` that defines those objects.